# First and last observation being cut in half when using `layout.xaxis.range`

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, r-plotly, plotly.js

How can I avoid the first and last observation plotted being cut in half when using `layout.xaxis.range`?

This becomes very obvious when using a standard [plotly example](https://plotly.com/r/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays) modified as a candlestick chart (first and last candle of December 1st 2015 and January 15 2015 respectively):

```
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "candlestick",
  x     = ~df$Date,
  open  = ~df$AAPL.Open,
  high  = ~df$AAPL.High,
  low   = ~df$AAPL.Low,
  close = ~df$AAPL.Close
)
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    title = "Time Series with Custom Date-Time Format",
    xaxis = list(
      type = "date",
      range = c('2015-12-01', '2016-01-15')
    )
  )
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a pic demonstrating what you mean? Is there just not enough room on the graph to fit the width of the graphic? Would an offset, or slightly expanding the range help?

Comment: Well there is a way when working with `lubridate`. However, isn't there a more elegant way of doing this?

`range = c(as.character(as.Date('2015-12-01') - hours(12)), as.character(as.Date('2016-01-15') + hours(12)))`

Comment: This behavior is expected as the candlestick is drawn at point (x,y) and half the candle will take half the horizontal space. You could avoid this either using the "right" data at first or setting the range at (x-1, x+1) as explained in the comment above.

Comment: Correct, either `x - 0.5` and `x + 0.5` when working with item-wise observations or `x - hours(12)` and `x - hours(12)` when working with dates on the left and right side of the x-axis respectively. However, a preferred solution (also with regard to rendering times - the answer/comment section provided by @user2554330 below) would be offsetting the charting area from the frame surrounding the charting area (likewise to a standard R plot), thereby, providing space for the full candle.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying a range in the plot, take a subset of your data and plot that with the default range.  For example,

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df <- subset(df, Date >= "2015-12-01" & Date <= "2016-01-15")

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "candlestick",
  x     = ~df$Date,
  open  = ~df$AAPL.Open,
  high  = ~df$AAPL.High,
  low   = ~df$AAPL.Low,
  close = ~df$AAPL.Close
)
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    title = "Time Series with Custom Date-Time Format",
    xaxis = list(
      type = "date"
    )
  )
fig
```

Note that this does a character based comparison of the dates; since your data are in YYYY-MM-DD format, this works, but in general it would be safer to convert to the Date type before the subsetting.

Comment: True, however, when compared using the `microbenchmark` package the first definition of `fig <- ...` (rendering the whole plot) takes approximately 1 millisecond whereas the second (just showing the range) takes 0.1 milliseconds.

Comment: @user2554330 Your snippet only produces a blank chart.

Comment: @vestland:  Perhaps your system downloads the dates in a different format, or there was a glitch and you didn't download anything at all.

Comment: @user2554330 I don't think so. The snippet in the question worked just fine.

Comment: The snippet provided by user2554330 works fine on my side as well...

Comment: @vestland:  So what does `df$Date` look like before and after the subsetting?  I'll fix the answer to work on your system too, but I need some information about what went wrong.

Comment: @ Running `df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')` produces a dataframe with 506 observations of 11 variables. Runnindg`df <- subset(df, Date >= "2015-12-01" & Date <= "2016-01-15")` produces an empty dataframe.

Comment: @vestland:  and what does `df$Date` look like before subsetting?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue seems to be related to your dates not being in the expected format (saved as text). Fixing this should avoid the x range being cut halfway.

```
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)  # Instead of keeping the date as character

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "candlestick",
  x     = ~df$Date,
  open  = ~df$AAPL.Open,
  high  = ~df$AAPL.High,
  low   = ~df$AAPL.Low,
  close = ~df$AAPL.Close
)
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    title = "Time Series with Custom Date-Time Format"
  )
fig
```

For your range related needs, I'd take a look at the [range slider](https://plotly.com/r/range-slider/) and [range selector buttons](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-with-range-selector-buttons) configuration.

Comment: The answer provided plots the whole time series and therefore provides the full candles on the left and right side of the graph. When changing ranges using the range slider or alternatively `xaxis = list(type = "date", range = c('2015-12-01', '2016-01-15'))` in the second part of the code (`fig <- fig %>% ...`) the problem arises again even when changing to `POSIXct`.

Comment: Also with regard to rendering times of a whole plot versus showing a sub-period only (see answer/comment section by @user255430), a preferred solution would be offsetting the charting area from the frame surrounding the charting area (likewise to a standard R plot), thereby, providing space for the full candle.